# Children not keeping their position within animated parent/wrapper element

Tags: jquery, animation, mousemove

I have a parent element that I set to animate its position in accordance with the mouse position and movments.

The issue I have is the children are not moving "with" the parent. I don't want their position inside the wrapper to move at all. I would expect it to stay in the same place as the parent moves around since I am only animating the parent but it seems to move differently. Everything should move together at the same time.

So basically it should look like its keeping its position AS the parent moves around. So it should move WITH the parent, as the parent moves. Instead of bouncing around inside.
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

```js
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
  $(".mouse-mover").css({
    "margin-left": -(event.pageX * 0.03),
    "margin-top": -(event.pageY * 0.03)
  });
});
```

```css
.Animated-Bottle-Wrap {
  display:block;
  width:241px;
  height:485px;
  background:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.45);
  background-image: url("http://customlabeledwines.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/wine-hero.png");
}

.btl-sprite {
    background-image: url("http://customlabeledwines.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/btl-sprite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:231px;
    margin-left:66px;
}

.btl-design {
    width: 83px;
    height: 127px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
    top:235px;
    margin-left:65px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mouse-mover Animated-Bottle-Wrap">
<!-- Labels -->
<div id="label-slideshow" class="mouse-mover">
<div class="btl-design btl-sprite"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
 $(".mouse-mover").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "translate("+-(event.pageX * 0.03)+"px,"+ -(event.pageY * 0.03)+"px)"
   
  });


});
```

```css
.Animated-Bottle-Wrap {
  display:block;
  width:241px;
  height:485px;
  background:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.45);
  background-image: url("http://customlabeledwines.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/wine-hero.png");
}

.btl-sprite {
    background-image: url("http://customlabeledwines.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/btl-sprite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:231px;
    margin-left:66px;
}

.btl-design {
    width: 83px;
    height: 127px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
    top:235px;
    margin-left:65px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mouse-mover Animated-Bottle-Wrap">
<!-- Labels -->
<div id="label-slideshow" class="">
<div class="btl-design btl-sprite"></div>
</div>
```